# antonioribeiro/countries How to remove "Useless" entries?

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm using the PHP package https://github.com/antonioribeiro/countries and it works great but there is a single issue that is really bugging me that I can find pretty much 0 information on.

How do I get rid of the entries it provides that are sort of nonsensical? For example "Europe Union", etc... It sticks them on the end and I can't seem to find a property of the "country" that I can filter them by.

I'm sort of a bit confused as to why any of these are even considered "Countries" when they are actually just groups of countries? Like for example it doesn't really make much sense for a user to set their country as "Europe Union". It makes way more sense for them to just set it as "Netherlands" or whatever.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Can you post your output or the dataset you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the documentation, you can use pluck to `handpick the columns you need:

```
// Generate a list of States
$countries->where('name.common', 'United States')
    ->first()
    ->hydrateStates()
    ->states
    ->sortBy('name')
    ->pluck('name', 'postal');

// returns

[
    "AL": "Alabama",
    "AK": "Alaska",
    "AZ": "Arizona",
    "AR": "Arkansas",
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but there is a *record_type* property you can filter on. As of July 2021, setting *record_type* to 'country' gives 267 countries and excludes *Europe Union*.

```
public static function getCountries(): array
{
    return (new CountryLibrary())
        ->where('record_type', 'country')
        ->sortBy('name.common')
        ->all()
        ->pluck('name.common', 'cca3')
        ->prepend('United States of America', 'USA')
        ->prepend('Canada', 'CAN')
        ->prepend('-- Select --', '')
        ->toArray();
}
```

There is a similar property for states/provinces. This is how I am generating a list of states for any given country.

```
$states = $country
    ->states
    ->filter(function($state){
        $isAState = $state->extra->record_type === 'state';
        $stateHasName = $state->extra->gn_name <> '';

        return $isAState && $stateHasName;
    })
    ->sortBy('extra.gn_name')
    ->transform(function ($state) {
        return [
            'id' => substr($state->code_hasc, -2),
            'text' => $state->extra->gn_name,
        ];
    })
    ->pluck('text', 'id');
```